# Find the vector equation of line in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> > Find the vector equation of a line which contains the two points $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(4, 5, 6) $

**Hints only.**

I know $x = a + t*d$ where $a, d$ are vectors and $t$ is a scalar.

We can have $a =\{<1, 2, 3>, <4, 5, 6> \}$ as two options of the vectors.

The difficulty is in finding $d$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You want both $u := (1,2,3)$ and $v: = (4,5,6)$ to lie on the line, that is for some values of $t_u, t_v$, we want 
$$ a + t_ud = u,\qquad a + t_vd = v $$
as we are free in choosing $t_u$ and $t_v$ (we just want them to lie on the line $a + \mathbf R d$ somewhere, let $t_u = 0$ and $t_1 = 1$, this gives 
$$ a = u, \qquad a + d = v $$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Ah I see, so $d = v - u$?

Comment: But dont we need $t$ to be constant?

Comment: No, on the line $\ell: x = a + td$, $t$ runs through every real number and for each value gives a different point on $\ell$. And. Yes, $d = v-u$ is a possible choice.

Comment: Ah, so the variable is $t$?

Comment: Yes.  That is part the definition of $x=a+td$ as the equation for the line: an equation that yields all points $x$ on the line, parameterized by the real number $t$..  Only $a$ and $d$ are constants.